# Ruta absoluta md5sum

Tags: linux, unix, shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash

comprobacion ()   
{  
        fichero=$1;  
        #La variable a almacena el valor actual del checksum  
        a=$(ls -p $fichero | grep -v / | grep -v Script_Md| xargs md5sum);  
        #La variable  b almacena el contenido del fichero listamd5sum  
        b=$(cat $HOME/MD/ocupacion);  
        echo  -e  "\nChecksums actuales:\n"  
        echo "$a";  
        echo  -e "\nChecksums orginales:\n"  
        echo "$b";  
        if [ "$a" = "$b" ]; then #Compara el contenido de las variables a y b  
                echo -e  "\n--------------------------------------------------------------"  
                echo "| El contenido de los archivos del directorio no ha cambiado |"  
                echo "--------------------------------------------------------------"  
        else   
                echo -e "\n-------------------------------------------------------

    ----"  
                    echo "| El contenido de los archivos del directorio ha cambiado |"  
                    echo "-----------------------------------------------------------"       
            fi  
    }  

    fichero="$1";  
    if [ -e "$HOME/MD/ocupacion" ]; then  
            if [ -z "$fichero" ]; then  
                    echo "¡Directorio vacío!"  
            elif [ -e "$fichero" ]; then  
                    comprobacion $fichero #Llamada a la funcion comprobacion  
            else   
                    echo "¡El directorio no existe"  
            fi        
    else  
            if [ -z "$fichero" ]; then  
                    echo "¡Directorio vacío!"  
            elif [ -e "$fichero" ]; then  
                    #Se excluyen aquellos ficheros que son directorios, tambien el Script_Md y se calcula el checksum de los restantes  
                    ls -p "$fichero" | grep -v / | grep -v "Script_Md" | xargs md5sum >$HOME/MD/ocupacion  
            else   
                    echo "¡El directorio no existe"  
            fi  
    fi
```

El problema está cuando inicializo la variable **a** en la función comprobación. El argumento que recibe el script es la ruta absoluta de un directorio. Ahora bien, si el directorio que le paso es mi pwd actual no me da ningún problema, se da cuando, por ejemplo: Mi pwd es $HOME, paso como argumento el directorio /etc, en la ejecución del script sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No encuentra los ficheros, md5sum no los encuentra, ya que no están listados con ruta absoluta. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que `ls -p $fichero | grep -v / | grep -v Script_Md` se liste con la ruta absoluta de los ficheros?

Comment: ¿Has probado a incluir en xargs el path absoluto? Algo como `xargs -i{} md5sum ${fichero}/{}`

Comment: Funciona. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para dejar la pregunta como respondida, aclaro mi comentario aquí:

`xargs` permite, mediante *placeholders*, completar los parámetros que se le pasarán al comando a llamar:

```
xargs -i{} md5sum ${fichero}/{}
```

De este modo, el comando md5sum recibe como parámetro la concatenación de la ruta, contenida en la variable `fichero`, y el nombre del archivo.